# Increase times exist Chrome Notification

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension, and in my case, i want to show a notification.
Although i set priority is 2, but it just show 20 seconds then disappear.
Do you have any way to increase time show notification ?

Comment: Use [requireInteraction](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/notifications#type-NotificationOptions) option: [Prevent chrome.notifications API from hiding my notification after a few seconds](//stackoverflow.com/q/20326926)

Comment: Thanks wOxxOm, that exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

Like wOxxOm comment, we can use **requireInteraction** to increase time show notification.

> Indicates that the notification should remain visible on screen until the user activates or dismisses the notification. This defaults to false.

Example :

```
 chrome.notifications.create(warningId,
    {
        iconUrl: chrome.runtime.getURL('images/icon-48.png'),
        title: data.word.toUpperCase(),
        type: 'basic',
        message: "Test message",
        buttons: [{ title: 'Close' }],
        isClickable: true,
        priority: 2,
        requireInteraction: true
    },
    function() {});
```